# Invokling a MBean operation running on tomcat, remotely

Tags: tomcat, rmi, jmx

I have a written an MBean to get certain properties of all running threads. Running this on Tomcat.

```
..
public String dumpThreads() {

        ThreadMXBean threadMX = ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean();
        long[] allThreadIDs = threadMX.getAllThreadIds();
        ThreadInfo[] threadsInfo = threadMX.getThreadInfo(allThreadIDs, 10);
        StringBuilder threadDumpSB = new StringBuilder();

        threadDumpSB.append ("THREAD DUMP - " + (new SimpleDateFormat ("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss")).format(new Date()) );
        threadDumpSB.append ("\n\n");
        threadDumpSB.append ("Thread count: " + Integer.toString(threadsInfo.length) );
        threadDumpSB.append ("\n\n\n");

        for (ThreadInfo threadInfo : threadsInfo) {
            threadDumpSB.append ("ID: " + Long.toString(threadInfo.getThreadId()) + "\n");
            threadDumpSB.append ("Name: " + threadInfo.getThreadName() + "\n");
            threadDumpSB.append ("State: " + threadInfo.getThreadState() + "\n");
            StackTraceElement[] stacktraceElements = threadInfo.getStackTrace();
            for (StackTraceElement stElm : stacktraceElements) 
                threadDumpSB.append ("    at " + stElm.toString() + "\n");
            threadDumpSB.append ("\n");
        }

        return (threadDumpSB.toString());

    }
..
```

I am able to see this through jconsole under: *Application>Server>Server>Operations* and also via  http://*servername*:8080/manager/jmxproxy

```
Name: Application:Name=Server,Type=Server
modelerType: org.puneet.mbeans.Server
Uptime: 3156547
```

Now, I would like to execute the *`dumpThreads()`* method remotely.

This is where I have go to so far:

```
JMXServiceURL url = new JMXServiceURL("service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:8008/jmxrmi");
JMXConnector jmxc = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(url, null);
MBeanServerConnection mbsc = jmxc.getMBeanServerConnection();
```

I am able to connect to the server & get a list of mbeans, etc. Not sure how to get a handle to my mbean & then invoke the dumpThreads() operation.

```
ObjectName mbeanName = new ObjectName("Application:Name=Server,Type=Server"); ...?
```

Thanks in advance.

Puneet

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out!

```
...
MBeanServerConnection mbsc = jmxc.getMBeanServerConnection();
...
ObjectName mbeanName = new ObjectName("Application:Name=Server,Type=Server");
Object o = mbsc.invoke(mbeanName, "dumpThreads", null, null);
System.out.println(o);
...
```